# What is the use case of the <bdo> element?

Tags: html, internationalization

First of all, I understand the difference between the attribute `dir` of a `bdo` element and any other element. If we have the following text:

```
Hello world!
```

`<bdo dir="rtl">Hello world!</bdo>` will show the mirrored version of the text as:

```
!dlrow ,olleH
```

And `<p dir="rtl">Hello world!</bdo>` will show the text just as normally in the Arabic language:

```
!Hello, world
```

Why does the bdo element even exist? I checked MDN for use cases and didn't find any there. The example showed there seems useless for me in any real world application. Are there any rtl languages where mirrored text is considered normal? Or there's another use case of this element?

UPD: I even found a [tweet](https://twitter.com/fantasai/status/926926730949828609) from a W3C member saying that:

> Recommending BDO would be just always and forever wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is useful in cases where the text is in a language that is written from right to left (RTL), such as Arabic, Hebrew, or Persian, and needs to be displayed correctly on a web page.

For example, suppose you have a web page with some text in English, followed by a quote in Arabic. Without using the bdo element, the Arabic quote would be displayed in the same direction as the English text, which would be incorrect. By using the bdo element with the "rtl" attribute, you can ensure that the Arabic text is displayed correctly from right to left.

Comment: I'm not an i18n specialist but I'm pretty sure that the Arabic text is being displayed the correct way even without this element. At least for Chrome it's done automatically.